# VM10:182 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated

Tags: reactjs, auth0

VM10:182 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

i try to run but gave error : VM10:182 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

i just visited to network tab in developers tool and check network and check if connectivity has been set to offline or slow 3G , it was set to offline. All i do is just set it to no-throttling and here it work fine for me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjBkN.png)